# Is it possible to email the current page of a pdf I am reading?

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-reader

Is it possible to email the current page of a PDF I am reading? In Adobe Reader or any PDF reader. I don't want to email the whole file.

Comment: use the print page option in your pdf viewer to save as a new pdf and send it.

Comment: Right. I was hoping for one that emails directly without printing and saving first. I have a pdf reader on Android that does that.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-selected-pages-acrobat-reader.html

Answer (score 0):

Outlook cannot edit PDF files for sending (I have never seen this type of function).  You need to open the file in Adobe, isolate the page, save as a new, smaller PDF, and email the new single page PDF

Comment: I have a pdf reader on Android that emails from within the app. There's no need to use Outlook or a mail client.

Comment: you are saying it uses your email without your credentials or that it uses another email service? so the recipient does not know it is from you? if it is sent from you I would be concerned for an app that is able to send emails from me without opening the client.

Comment: You really need to save the page you need. Then it does not depend up Email client at all. That seems to me to be the best way. Email client does not matter and you have a saved file as record.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a single page, use the Print to PDF feature when you are printing. For example if you are using the chrome pdf reader:

[image: chrome pdf reader] Click print or `Ctrl+P`

[image]
Change printer to Pdf

[image]

Chose the Page

[image]

Then Hit Print